# Remove xmlns information from generated file?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am using Elementtree to parse an xml file, edit the contents and write to a new xml file. I have this all working apart form one issue. When I generate the file there are a lot of extra lines containing namespace information. Here are some snippets of code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.register_namespace("", "http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema")
tree = ET.parse('ethernet.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

commands = root.findall('{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}'
                        'VIEW/{http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema}COMMAND')

for command in commands:
    all1.append(list(command.iter()))
```

And a sample of the output file, with the erroneous line `xmlns="http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema`:

```
<COMMAND xmlns="http://clish.sourceforge.net/XMLSchema" help="Interface specific description" name="description">
            <PARAM help="Description (must be in double-quotes)" name="description" ptype="LINE" />
            <CONFIG />
</COMMAND>
```

How can I remove this with elementtree, can I? Or will i have to use some regex (I am writing a string to the file)?

Comment: Why is that line erroneous? The `COMMAND` tag falls under that namespace, as do its children. Removing the `xmlns` attribute would completely change the meaning of the XML document.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am wondering because the file I am copying has none of that xmlns stuff in it, just once at the start. Here is the file I am copying, I generate a very similar file but every command line has the xmlns, does this matter or is it the same thing really? http://pastebin.com/LhdfWAhG My problem is that this is a klish file and it may not like this syntax and break.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is there a parent element that you are adding the `<COMMAND>` elements to? Does that parent element have the namespace declared? ElementTree is not that smart about namespaces in general, but it is hard to figure out the specifics here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am adding it to the view element as seen in the pastebin there, that is it's parent if that is what you mean? the xmlns is declared at the top of the file only. Basically I want to copy that working file and am worried that this syntax will not be accepted by the software they are using, klish. It may work fine, this is more of a 'in case' as I know their file works fine as is, so I don't want to deviate from what they have.

Comment: What python version is this? I see that the version that comes with Python 2.7 claims have a better serializer that should remove these redundant namespace declarations. If your target uses a compliant XML parser, it'll work just fine, btw. Why don't you try it out and see?

Comment: @MartijnPieters 2.7 so it should have removed them hmm. I can test it soon, hopefully it will just work! Can be finicky. Thanks!